# How does escaping work on DB insert in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, escaping

I have a basic resource, and I'd like to know if I must escape form data or laravel does it for me behind the scenes?

```
public function store(ProductRequest $request, Product $product)
{
    $fields = [
        'owner_id' => 1,
        'title' => $request -> title,
    ];

    $product -> create($fields);

    return view('product');
}
```

if I pass

```
';drop table products;
```

as the title, it is being stored as is, yet I still have the table, how?

in App\Http\Kernel.php I've the default middlewares

laravel -v: 2.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel uses parameter binding in order to protect you against SQL injection out of the box if you use Eloquent.

If you need to use the query builder than you should use [this](https://laravel.com/docs/master/database#running-queries) approach to bind parameters passed to the query for SQL injection protection.

Comment: Minor addition: as long as you don't use query builder methods with `raw` in their name, you should be fine.